# How to get string value of integer in the EAX register

Tags: gdb

I'm trying to determine what the string value of an integer in the %eax register is.

I'm using gdb, the command

```
(gdb) info registers
```

outputs:

```
eax            0x804c800    134531072
ecx            0xf  15
edx            0x1  1
ebx            0xffffd324   -11484
esp            0xffffd24c   0xffffd24c
ebp            0xffffd288   0xffffd288
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x8048fca    0x8048fca <strings_not_equal>
eflags         0x286    [ PF SF IF ]
cs             0x23 35
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x2b 43
es             0x2b 43
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x63 99
```

i want to know how to get a word out of the value `134531072`

I tried `print /s %eax` but im getting an error `A syntax error in expression, near %eax'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to print the value of eax

You can use

```
(gdb) info registers $eax
(gdb) print $eax
```

If you want to print a string pointed to by $eax try

```
(gdb) x/s $eax
```

For more info about x command see http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html

Answer (score 4):

This is the way to do it:

```
print (char []) $rax
```

if `rax` points to a string in memory, instead use:

```
printf "%s", $rax
```

Answer (score 1):

First the registers in gdb are referred to with $ not %, so it would be print/s $eax. But this does not print register as characters (to me it looks like it should).

This however does: print (char[4]) $eax.

(Character in low order byte is printed first.)